# How do I get node data by clicking a node in the diagram?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I'm making a dynamic genogram in GoJS, where I want to be able to click a parent node, click a button in HTML that adds the child and links it to the parents. For this I need to be able to get the key from the parent node by clicking on it in the diagram.

I was thinking I'd have to use the `addDiagramListener()` function but I think that function is only for changes in appearance of the node e.g. changing the color of the node on click and not for getting node data.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. The two most common are to implement a ["ChangedSelection"](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/events.html#ChangedSelection) Diagram event, and looking at all selected nodes (or just the first one: `myDiagram.selection.first()`) and inspecting the `node.data` or just `node.key` (which is a shortcut for `node.data.key`)

And to do something similar on each individual node by setting [selectionChanged](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Part.html#selectionChanged) on your Node template. This function will be called every time a given node is selected or deselected.

There's a simple live example of `selectionChanged` being used here: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/selection.html#SelectionAppearanceChanges

Comment: Thank you so much.

i did this:
`
getNodeKey = function (diagram){
    diagram.addDiagramListener("ChangedSelection", function (event){
        node = diagram.selection.first();
        console.log(node.key);
    })
}`

This worked but i'm not using the `event` value that i used in the function. Would this be necessary? because in most examples i've seen the event parameter needs to be there.

Comment: You do not need to use that param. However, it has a reference to things that may be useful, and for safety you could use event.diagram to make the code slightly more general.